# Putting a for each loop inside a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have the need to search all servers in our domain for specific folders, I already have a script here

```
function Find-ComputersWithFolder {
    # Get all computers in the Active Directory domain
    $computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like 'servernamehere' }

    # Initialize an empty array to store the result
    $result = @()
 
    # Iterate through each computer
    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        $computerName = $computer.Name
 
        # Check if the folder C:\ASNEXT exists on the computer
        $folderExists = Test-Path "\\$computerName\C$\Windows\WinSxS\foldernamehere"
 
        # If the folder exists, add the computer name to the result list
        if ($folderExists) {
            $result += $computerName
        }
    }
 
    # Return the result array
    return $result
}
 
# Usage example for the Find-ComputersWithFolder function
 
# Find all computers with the folder
$computersWithFolder = Find-ComputersWithFolder
 
# Output the result
Write-Output "Computers with folder"
$computersWithFolder
```

what this does is searches all servers in the domain and looks for the folder that is specified in the line

```
$folderExists = Test-Path "\\$computerName\C$\Windows\WinSxS\foldernamehere"
```

However i have a long list of folders i would like to supply to this script so that it went through them instead of me having to manually specify the folder on the specific line

```
$folderExists = Test-Path "\\$computerName\C$\Windows\WinSxS\foldernamehere"
```

I tried the following amendment to the script, i put all the folder names in a text file and created a variable $Paths to which i used the get-content.

```
$paths = get-content C:\scripts\paths.txt
```

This works in that it fills the variable with the list of folders but when i change the line that actually searches to this

```
$folderExists = Test-Path "\\$computerName\C$\Windows\WinSxS\$paths"
```

I dont get any output, I suspect its is something to do with having to somehow get it to do a for-each through the list but i dont know how to get to that point.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I'd recommend making the serverlist and the folderlist parameters you provide for the function. This way you're not forced to use a hardcoded input file.  Next thing ... to speed up I'd use PowerShell remoting and `Invoke-Command` for the checks for the folders. You can provide a list of computer names to it. This way you'd query all servers  at once. 

Comment: Olaf makes an excellent point. Are you able to `Invoke-Command` these servers ?

Comment: Thank you Guys, As you suggested i added the server and folder list as params outside like this

# Specify the path to the text file containing the list of computer names
$computerList =  "C:\scripts\servers.txt"

# Specify the path to the text file containing the list of folder names
$folderList = "C:\scripts\paths.txt"

It it taking a while so when it is finished i will try the invoke-command to speed things up <3  TY

Answer (score 1):

> "I suspect its is something to do with having to somehow get it to do a for-each through the list..."

This is correct, you're missing an inner loop to test *each path in `$paths` for each computer in `$computers`*, however, what I would recommend you to do is to remove complexity from your function, the query for Active Directory computers should be outside of your function, then you can leverage the pipeline by taking [`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.3#valuefrompipelinebypropertyname-argument):

```bash
function Test-NetworkPath {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, Mandatory)]
        [Alias('Name')]
        [string] $ComputerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [string[]] $Path
    )

    process {
        foreach ($p in $Path) {
            $pathToTest = '\\{0}\C$\Windows\WinSxS\{1}' -f $ComputerName, $p
            if (Test-Path $pathToTest) {
                $pathToTest
            }
        }
    }
}

$paths = Get-Content C:\scripts\paths.txt
Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -like 'servernamehere'" |
    Test-NetworkPath -Path $paths
```

In this example the [`.Name` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adobject.name?view=activedirectory-management-10.0#microsoft-activedirectory-management-adobject-name) from each [`ADComputer` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adcomputer?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) is bound thru the pipeline to the `$ComputerName` parameter.

Comment: Thank you Santiago, I will try this next as it is certainly less complet than the script i have running at the moment.

Appreciate your help my friend

Comment: Hey Santiago, unfortunatly that didnt work

Test-NetworkPath : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ComputerName' because it is an empty string.
At line:23 char:5
+     Test-NetworkPath -Path $paths
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (CN=IN1GRAWUS001...innovene,DC=com:PSObject) [Test-NetworkPath], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Test-NetworkPath

Comment: @MartynJeffrey is your code an exact copy of the code in my answer? do you have empty lines in your `paths.txt` file?

Comment: it is a direct copy paste

this si the bottom of the code

$paths = Get-Content C:\scripts\paths.txt
Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like 'in1gra*' } |
    Test-NetworkPath -Path $paths

no spaces in text file, infact i emptied it to only include one line of text (folder path)

Comment: i just tried it with your version of get-adcomputer

Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -like 'servernamehere'" 

instead of the one i was using

 Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like 'in1gra*' }

Comment: @MartynJeffrey im not sure, I don't see anything wrong with my code. As long as the file exists and has the folder names in it then you shouldn't get errors

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it with

```
function Search-ComputersForFolders {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$FilePath
    )

    # Read the folder names from the text file
    $folderNames = Get-Content C:\scripts\paths.txt

    # Get all computers in the network
    $computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like 'servernames'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

    # Initialize an empty array to store the found folders
    $foundFolders = @()

    # Loop through each computer and search for the folders
    foreach ($computer in $computers) {
        # Construct the UNC path to the computer's C drive
        $uncPath = "\\$computer\C$"

        # Check if the UNC path is accessible
        if (Test-Path -Path $uncPath) {
            # Loop through each folder name and search for it
            foreach ($folderName in $folderNames) {
                # Construct the full path to the folder
                $folderPath = Join-Path -Path $uncPath -ChildPath $folderName

                # Check if the folder exists
                if (Test-Path -Path $folderPath -PathType Container) {
                    # Add the found folder to the array
                    $foundFolders += Get-Item -Path $folderPath
                }
            }
        }
    }
     
    # Output the found folders
    return $foundFolders
}
    
# Usage example for the Search-ComputersForFolders.ps1 script
    
# Example: Search for folders on all computers in the network
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$folderFilePath = "C:\scripts\paths.txt"
$foundFolders = Search-ComputersForFolders -FilePath $folderFilePath
    
# Output the found folders
foreach ($folder in $foundFolders) {
    Write-Output "Found folder: $($folder.FullName)"
}
```